# Mapping nodes sizes and adding legends in cytoscape network

Tags: python, networkx, cytoscape

I used networkx package in python to construct multiple networks, where each represents a biological experiment. I then exported these networks as gml files to visualize in cytoscape and make comparisons. In each file, I have two attributes for nodes- i.e., count and color. In cytoscape, I assign the node size to its count. However, there is a huge difference between the counts of nodes, for instance some have a count of 100 while others have a count of 50,000. I would like map the sizes of all nodes in all cytoscape networks to one scale and also have a legend indicating the relative sizes.  An example is shown in right side of the image below! I hope you can help me!

[image]

[Image source](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1002503)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the first part of the question is to construct a log(count) column.  That should give you a better range to map into node size.

The best 'shipping' solution to creating a legend in a command called 'Create Legend...' found in the Style control panel pop-up menu.  That exports a graphics file, but doesn't do an adequate job of it.  I'm working on an app called Legend Creator, which will add annotations to the canvas for a legend.  It's in development on the github/cytoscape repo.

Comment: Thank you so much Adam! I did the log of the count and it works fine. I tried to implement the legend by using R igraph but couldn't do it. So, I just made the legends manually- although they are a bit ugly but  it should be fine for now..